# R shinydashboard + highcharter: arguments are not named in hc_add_series

Tags: r, shinydashboard, r-highcharter

I'm trying to create a dashboard where a state can be selected and the graph is updated by that selection, but I get this error:

> 'Warning: Error in : 'df', 'hcaes(x = date, y = injured)' arguments
> are not named in hc_add_series   [No stack trace available]'

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(highcharter)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = 'Test Dashboard'),
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody(fluidPage(selectInput('select',
                                                        label = 'States',
                                                        choices = unique(opts),
                                                        selected = 'Alabama'),
                                            box(title = "Stock",
                                                status = "primary",
                                                solidHeader = TRUE,
                                                collapsible = TRUE,
                                                highchartOutput('plot')))))

server <- function(input,
                   output) {
  output$plot <- renderHighchart({
    df <- reactive({
      df <- massShooting2018.order %>%
        filter(state %in% input$select) %>%
        group_by(date) %>%
        summarise(
          dead = sum(dead),
          injured = (sum(injured)),
          total = sum(total)
        )
    })


    highchart(type = "stock") %>%
      hc_chart("line",
        name = "base",
        hcaes(x = date)
      ) %>%
      hc_add_series(df,
        name = "Total",
        type = "line",
        hcaes(
          x = date,
          y = total
        )
      ) %>%
      hc_add_series(df,
        name = "Dead",
        type = "line",
        hcaes(
          x = date,
          y = dead
        )
      ) %>%
      hc_add_series(df,
        name = "Injured",
        type = "line",
        hcaes(
          x = date,
          y = injured
        )
      ) %>%
      hc_tooltip(
        crosshairs = TRUE,
        shared = TRUE,
        borderWidth = 2,
        table = TRUE
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[DataSource](https://www.kaggle.com/hemil26/mass-shootings-in-united-states-20182022)

**using the previous dataset:**

```
massShooting2018 <- read.csv('shootings_2018.csv')

massShooting2018.clean <- massShooting2018 %>%
  clean_names() %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(date))

massShooting2018.order <- massShooting2018.clean %>%
  group_by(date, state) %>%
  summarise(dead = sum(dead),
            injured = sum(injured),
            total = sum(total),
            description, .groups = 'drop')

opts <- massShooting2018.order %>%
  sample_frac(1) %>%
  select(state) %>%
  arrange(state)
```

**Thank you very much for reading and I hope I can solve this problem.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call of `df` after reactive function should be `df()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(highcharter)
library(janitor)
library(lubridate)

massShooting2018 <- read.csv('shootings_2018.csv')

massShooting2018.clean <- massShooting2018 %>%
  clean_names() %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(date))

massShooting2018.order <- massShooting2018.clean %>%
  group_by(date, state) %>%
  summarise(dead = sum(dead),
            injured = sum(injured),
            total = sum(total),
            description, .groups = 'drop')

opts <- massShooting2018.order %>%
  sample_frac(1) %>%
  select(state) %>%
  arrange(state)



ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = 'Test Dashboard'),
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody(fluidPage(selectInput('select',
                                                        label = 'States',
                                                        choices = unique(opts),
                                                        selected = 'Alabama'),
                                            box(title = "Stock",
                                                status = "primary",
                                                solidHeader = TRUE,
                                                collapsible = TRUE,
                                                highchartOutput('plot')))))

server <- function(input, 
                   output) 
{
  output$plot <- renderHighchart({
    
    df <- reactive({df <- massShooting2018.order %>%
      filter(state %in% input$select) %>%
      group_by(date) %>%
      summarise(dead = sum(dead),
                injured = (sum(injured)),
                total = sum(total))})
    
    
    highchart(type = 'stock') %>%
      hc_chart('line',
               name = 'base',
               hcaes(x = date)) %>%
      hc_add_series(df(),
                    name = 'Total',
                    type = 'line',
                    hcaes(x = date,
                          y = total)) %>%
      hc_add_series(df(),
                    name = 'Dead',
                    type = 'line',
                    hcaes(x = date,
                          y = dead)) %>%
      hc_add_series(df(),
                    name = 'Injured',
                    type = 'line',
                    hcaes(x = date,
                          y = injured)) %>%
      hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE,
                 shared = TRUE, 
                 borderWidth = 2,
                 table = TRUE)})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]